# Using subquery result in WHERE IN in another subqueries (optimization)

Tags: mysql, optimization

This has been bugging me for some time now, as a newbie I'm not sure what I should exactly look for. After several hours of Googling I wasn't able to find a satisfying answer.

I have a relatively complex query which I have stripped and simplified to become:

```
SELECT field_a1,
       field_a2,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_b
        WHERE  field_b1 IN (SELECT field_x1
                            FROM   table_x) AND field_b2 = 1) AS new_field_1,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_c
        WHERE  field_c1 IN (SELECT field_x1
                            FROM   table_x) AND field_c2 = 2) AS new_field_2,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_d
        WHERE  field_d1 IN (SELECT field_x1
                            FROM   table_x) AND field_d2 = 3) AS new_field_3
FROM   table_a
WHERE  field_a1 IN (SELECT field_x1
                    FROM   table_x)
```

In the original query, I have a about 30 of those `new_field_*`. Everything seems to work fine and I'm getting some very satisfying results (end results and performance).

My problem is that this query:

```
SELECT field_x1
FROM   table_x
```

is repeated a quite large number of times (30 * number of rows returned) and is always used as a set in which the `WHERE IN` will look for matches.

**My question:**

Is it possible to execute this small query only once and keep that result and use it repeatedly?

The only two (ridiculous) things I could think of were something like this (imaginary solution):

```
temp = (SELECT field_x1
        FROM   table_x)
SELECT field_1
FROM   table_1
WHERE  field_1 IN temp
```

Or executing this query once on the client side (a webserver running PHP) then appending the result to the future queries using something like this:

```
$IN_Condition = implode(',', $stmt->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));
$sql_query = "SELECT field_1
              FROM   table_1
              WHERE  field_1 IN ($IN_Condition)"
```

Comment: Check this link. I hope you will get some idea to work around. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm

Comment: @V.P.Verma, thanks. I have considered temporary tables, but I still have to `SELECT` them in each of my subqueries. I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JOIN clauses, e.g. -

**edited:**

```
SELECT
  field_a1,
  COUNT(b.field_b1) new_field_1,
  COUNT(c.field_c1) new_field_2,
  COUNT(d.field_d1) new_field_3
FROM
  table_a a
JOIN table_x x
  ON x.field_x1 = a.field_a1
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON b.field_b1 = x.field_x1
LEFT JOIN table_c c
  ON c.field_c1 = x.field_x1
LEFT JOIN table_d d
  ON d.field_d1 = x.field_x1
GROUP BY
  a.field_a1
```

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't elaborated this point in my question. Fetching `new_field_*` undergoes more conditions than just `WHERE IN`. But +1 for the idea.

Comment: I believe that due to the complexity of my problem I'm not able to fully explain it. Thank you for trying.

Comment: I'm not gonna give up this easily, I have updated my question (particularly the main query) to further explain the conditions

Comment: Humm.. very interesting, this seems to approach not just my problem, but the whole query from a different angle. I have applied this idea to a portion my query and so far I'm getting the results I'm looking for (surprisingly 30% faster). But I noticed an increase in memory usage. I'll continue applying this to the whole query and I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: This indeed allowed me to create a situation where I don't have to execute a query many times, so I'll mark it as the accepted answer. BUT when I added the extra conditions and calculations there was more than 50% performance drop and extra memory usage (the opposite of what I was looking for). I think I'll end up running the result only once and use the result in `WHERE IN`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't need to do optimizations on the query, when the engine sees similar subqueries it fetches data only once. But you can try this query and see if it is faster:

```
SELECT a.field_a1, a.field_a2,
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM x
    WHERE x.field_x1 = b.field_b1
      AND b.field_b2 = 1) AS new_field_1,
   ...
FROM table_a, table_b b, ..., -- Query here the tables you need
     (SELECT field_x1
      FROM table_x) x
WHERE field_a1 IN x
```

You can also keep in memory your table, and compare data with your php engine, but it will be slower than working with the db engine.

EDIT: Each table you need will be queried once

EDIT 2: Reverse the logic!

Comment: It was the intuitive assumption for me (that the engine will only fetch the data once) but after some extensive testing and profiling I found that It's actually querying the table many times (30 * number of rows) times.

Comment: But `x` here is a temporary table, it can't be used in `WHERE IN` clause.